# Сделать кладку включенной по умолчанию

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт вкладок (tabs). Можно ли сделать активной первую вкладку по умолчанию без изменений в `html` коде?

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}


/* Fade in tabs */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, конечно можно. Добавь элементу класс `active` (и желательно через `classList`, а не `className`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто программно кликнуть по нужной вкладке. В примере ниже кликается по самой первой. Но можно поставить любую с помощью необходимого *CSS* селектора

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.querySelector('.tablinks:first-child').click();
});
```

```css
/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}


/* Fade in tabs */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас в примере работает, а у меня на сайте и вовсе перестали табы работать )

Comment: @АннаМатвеева а вы написали `DOMContentLoaded`?  скопируйте в точности. может вы не всё скопировали и у вас там ошибка синтаксиса в консоли отображается. нужно смотреть

Comment: Все верно, простите за невнимательность.